# FFmpeg: How to join multiple mono files into one multichannel file?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have e.g. 3 mono wav files. I would like to join them in one wave file which has 3 channels (not 2.1). The duration o this wave should inherit from the longest duration of mono files. I tried many commands, but no one of them gave me the expected result. Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## apad + join

One method is to use [apad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apad) on the two shorter inputs and then mix them with the [join](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#join) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i front_left.wav -i front_right.wav -i front_center.wav -filter_complex "[0]apad[FL];[1]apad[FR];[FL][FR][2]join=inputs=3:channel_layout=3.0:map=0.0-FL|1.0-FR|2.0-FC" output.wav
```

## apad + amerge + channelmap

Similar to above, but [channelmap](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelmap) (or pan) has to be added because [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) has no mapping functionality and assumes 2.1 instead of 3.0:

```
ffmpeg -i front_left.wav -i front_right.wav -i front_center.wav -filter_complex "[0]apad[FL];[1]apad[FR];[FL][FR][2]amerge=inputs=3,channelmap=map=FL-FL|FR-FR|LFE-FC" output.wav
```

---

- You can use [`ffprobe` to get the file durations](https://superuser.com/a/945604/).
- `ffmpeg -layouts` will provide a list of accepted channel names and layouts.

Comment: I used this command and the longest (00:42:91) audio is used as the last. Now the result audio's duration is 00:42:67, it's not the duration of any other audio. What is wrong?

Comment: @MichałAdamek I am unable to duplicate that behavior. Show the complete log from your command. You can use a pastebin site and put the link in a comment.

Comment: @MichałAdamek See alternative method in updated answer. I don't know why join is outputting a shorter duration.